# Using Regex to extract elements from text and append to dictionary

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a dictionary from this text that I am retrieving from a website by using some type of loop and a regex expression. I want the dictionary to look like this:

```
{36:30281, 36 2/3:30282, 37:30283, 37 1/3: 30283, 38:30284 etc..}
```

And here is the text I am retrieving from the website:

```
[option value="-1">Choose size</option>, option value="30281">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t36\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t/option>, option value="30282">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t36 2/3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t/option, option value="30283"\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t37 1/3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t/option, option value="30284">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t38\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</option>, option value="30285">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t38 2/3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</option>, option value="30286">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t39 1/3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</option>, option value="30287">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t40\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</option>, option value="30288">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t40 2/3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</option>, option value="30289">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t41 1/3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</option>]
```

I am not very good with regular expressions. Can anyone give me a solution that would help me do this?

Thank you

Comment: Try reading up on regular expressions in Python and come up with a solution (may or may not work) and test it, then post that here if you can't figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Well the thing is I couldn't figure out how to do it without using the " | " character, and that was causing some problems with my script. I was trying to use this regex: \\t(\d{2}\s+1\/3)|\\t(\d{2})|\\t(\d{2}\s+2\/3)

Comment: @chbchb55 take a look

Comment: You should add this to your question

Comment: To be honest, it is not *text* but part of a *DOM*. So better consider using a parser, eg `BeautifulSoup` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* use ([**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/FzOVgX/1/)):

```
value=\"(\d+)\"\D*(\d+(?:\ [\d/]+)?)
```

---

In `Python` this would be (using a dict comprehension):

```
import re 

junk_string = """
[option value="-1">Choose size</option>, option value="30281">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t36\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t/option>, option value="30282">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t36 2/3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t/option, option value="30283"\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t37 1/3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t/option, option value="30284">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t38\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</option>, option value="30285">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t38 2/3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</option>, option value="30286">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t39 1/3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</option>, option value="30287">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t40\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</option>, option value="30288">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t40 2/3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</option>, option value="30289">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t41 1/3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</option>]
"""

rx = re.compile(r'value=\"(\d+)\"\D*(\d+(?:\ [\d/]+)?)')
result = {m.group(2): m.group(1) 
            for m in rx.finditer(junk_string)}

print(result)
# {'36': '30281', '36 2/3': '30282', '37 1/3': '30283', '38': '30284', '38 2/3': '30285', '39 1/3': '30286', '40': '30287', '40 2/3': '30288', '41 1/3': '30289'}
```

But as already said in the comments, this is not actually text but part of a `DOM`, so at least *consider* using a parser instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working regular expression:

```
re.findall('\\t(\d{2}\s+\d\/\d)\\r\\n', [option value="-1">Choose size</option>, 'option value="30281">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t36\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t/option>, option value="30282">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t36 2/3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t/option, option value="30283"\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t37 1/3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t/option, option value="30284">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t38\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</option>, option value="30285">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t38 2/3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</option>, option value="30286">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t39 1/3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</option>, option value="30287">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t40\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</option>, option value="30288">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t40 2/3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</option>, option value="30289">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t41 1/3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</option>]')
```

This outputs:

```
['36 2/3', '37 1/3', '38 2/3', '39 1/3', '40 2/3', '41 1/3']
```

The way it works is mostly based off of yours but the changes are the following. I removed everything but the first section of your regular expression. I changed the `1` and `3` to `'\d'` which just means any number instead of just one and three. and then I added `'\\r\\n'` to the  end which isn't really necessary so you can take that off if you want but I guess it's just extra security for you.